# How can I detect and replace newline characters in a char[]?

Tags: java, char

My application connects to a server using sockets and reads data. The data is at most four chars long, but will occasionally be fewer than this. The data is appended by a CR LF combo, which I don't want to be present for the next step of processing.

Since I never want to read more than four characters, I have a `char[4]` buffer. Then, to account for the times where the data is less than four chars (and the CR and LF chars creep in), I have this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    String hexString = Integer.toHexString(buffer[i] | 0x10000).substring(1);
    if((hexString == "000d") || (hexString == "000a")) {
        buffer[i]='0';
    }
}
```

With judicious logging, I can see that the loop performs as expected, but does not overwrite the CR (U+000d) and LF (U+000a) characters. I expect the above code to replace any instances of carriage returns or line feeds with a '0', but the contents of the buffer does not appear to change.

To be honest this feels like a clumsy way of doing this anyway, so my question bifurcates:

1. What is wrong with my code? How can I fix it to perform as expected?
2. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Comparing on the hex values of the characters seems like an awkward and error-prone way to do this. Have you checked to see if your `if` statement is actually getting satisfied by newline characters?

Comment: Since you already have a good answer I'll just comment on  why your code does not work. You can not compare strings with == as that compares if the strings are the actual same instance. With .equals instead your code should at least work.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö Thanks for that. Kinda counter-intuitive, but it makes sense when you think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you'd be better off using `BufferedReader` and its `readLine()` method to start with:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, charset));
try {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        processLine(line);
    }
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```

The lines here won't have the line separators in, and you don't need to worry about whether a single call to `read` ends up half way through a line etc.

Comment: Thanks Jon - that does make a lot more sense.